# What is Adobe Experience Manager DB

Tags: adobe, aem

I would like to learn about Adobe Experience Manager DB.
Could anyone give me a reference to this concept.

Comment: The latest version of AEM uses [Apache Jackrabbit Oak](https://jackrabbit.apache.org/oak/) as a content repository, in lieu of a relational database

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For AEM repository concepts, you can go through [AEM platform](https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/aem/6-2/deploy/platform.html), [AEM RDBMS support](https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/aem/6-2/deploy/platform/rdbms-support-in-aem.html) and [AEM with MongoDB](https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/aem/6-2/deploy/platform/aem-with-mongodb.html).

For AEM connection with a SQL DB, you can read [here](https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/aem/6-2/develop/platform/jdbc.html).